# Is it possible to define templates outside of a Helm chat?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have multiple charts that all use the same templates. Is it possible to instruct helm to use some other templates directory, or have some shared templates that I can import/reference in some way? I would like to avoid the copy paste and have reusable templates, but at the same time keep the project/service per chart because in the future there will be some discrepancies.

How do you achieve DRY and re-usability in helm?

Comment: Have you tried packaging your shared templates as their own chart, and including them as [dependencies](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#chart-dependencies)?

Comment: I've managed to do it as a chart library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, that sounds like you want to use so called "Library Charts" ( [link to helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/library_charts/)).

To create one, you define a helm chart that does not actually create any Resources but only defines reusable templates and set the `type` property in the `chart.yml` to `library`:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: library-chart
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: library
version: 0.0.1
```

Then, you can include that helm chart as a dependency in your other charts and start using the templates defined there.

Comment: Yes, I succeeded it like that. Now I have only one line in every chart that just includes the template from the library and every chart has a zipped library in the `charts` directory, which is fine I guess, it needs to be self contained. I also tried the `merge` /override example. It doesn't work as expected if you have multiline strings in the template